# Drupal - RSS Item Edit - Seek Advice

Tags: drupal, rss, drupal-6, drupal-views

We use Drupal aggregator to get RSS feeds and present in views.  However we are seeking a RSS editor module that can perform the following functions:

*Allow to remove some RSS items if selected (not taken as-it-is from Aggregator module).  We experimented Yahoo pipes filtering function, however keyword filtering does not work perfectly. Human selection is desired. A module built to allow admin to do so is great.

*Allow to email or share a RSS item function next to the link.

Tried BuzzMonitor (suppose to have the above functions), but it did not work at all.

Any module is available to do the above work? Many thanks for your advice.  Happy Monday!

Answer (score 3):

I'd check out the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module (which can import each RSS item as its own node so excluding any is as easy as just unpublishing) along with Views to list them and ShareThis to add the ability to email or share them.

Comment: +1 - using feeds module at a current project exactly like that - all new feed entries get converted to nodes regularly on cron runs, and default to being unpublished. After that, editors can review the imported content and publish the wanted nodes selectively.